# Why would .append randomly fail in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery to add elements to a blank list.

on the page I have:

```
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

and I go through a loop like this in the script that's called from a dynamically created event handler.  (It's "onDrop" of a list item having been sorted with a drag operation)

```
var myListItemHTML;
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
  myListItemHTML += '<li id=listItem'+i+'>This is item number'+i+'</li>';
}

$('#myList').append(myListItemHTML);
```

and if I check after...

```
if ($('#myList li').length == 0 )
{
  alert('Going to crash now since I'm expecting list items')
}
```

roughly 95% of the time the list is populated, but about 5% of the time I hit my alert that's going to cause an exception later.

Has anyone run into this?  Is there a callback or way to know when/if the append really happens?

Comment: If you hit reload on one page 20 times, one time out of 20 it'll fail? Or do you have similar code spread across 20 pages, and one of those fails?

Comment: Have you got your code in a `$(document).ready` handler?

Comment: @sarnold: It's the same page hitting a button that causes the list to be refreshed with this code.  It's one out of twenty of those calls.

Comment: @lonesomeday - The function is not in the ready handler, but I have the appends surounded by $(document).ready(function () {//appends});

Comment: Can you confirm that your event is being triggered every time?

Comment: @keith - yup... walks right over the append calls in the debugger or output console in the logs.

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myListItemHTML;
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
  $('#myList').append('<li id=listItem'+i+'>This is item number'+i+'</li>');
}
```

Try just appending inside the for loop.

```
if ($('#myList li').length == 0 )
{
  alert('Going to crash now since I\'m expecting list items')
}
```

You need a `\` before the `'` so it doesn't conflict.

edit: jsfiddle that shows "undefined" http://jsfiddle.net/gyEre/1/

Comment: This is not a good approach. It results in too much Dom manipulation.

Comment: append in a for loop is a rich operation , try to form a string and append at the end...

Comment: It gets undefined because the first time around myListItemHTML isn't defined. http://jsfiddle.net/G7PMq/ it needs to be `var myListItemHYML = '';`

Comment: I do it at the end to reduce the total DOM manipulation. It does seem faster.  But I'd also tried in the loop as well and it's the same results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a longshot, because I'm making an assumption about your code beyond what was posted.  Here goes:

I had a problem with some code once, which worked perfectly in all Browsers except Chrome, wherein it would fail randomly and seemingly without cause.

My problem, ultimately, was that Chrome was actually executing my JavaScript *too fast*, and that it was throwing off some of the timing in some of the AJAX calls that were being made earlier.

My code was such that AJAX event A triggered, which then passed data to AJAX event B.  In Chrome only, though, I found that event B was on occasion occurring before event A, and that was the error condition.

If I recall, I think the solution was to force one key AJAX request to be made synchronously, though that should be used with care. Please see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

I hope that's not too vague to be helpful.  Good luck!

Comment: That is a true statement.  I'm actually calling this from an event handler on a user action that calls the list to be updated and this is in my refresh method.

Answer (score 1):

What I've learned is that I can't trust jquery for DOM manipulation called through dynamically created events.  I welcome someone to prove me wrong, but this approach:

```
addListItem = function (itemID, itemText)
{
   var li = document.createElement('li'); 
   li.setAttribute("id", itemID);

   var liText = document.createTextNode(itemText);
   li.appendChild(goalTextNode);

   document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(li); 

}

for (var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
  addListItem('listItem'+i, 'Item Text'+i);
}
```

will work 100% of the time and never fail.

Comment: "will work 100% of the time and never fail", said no programmer ever. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if the script in which the prepend function is used in the -tag, it will not work because the script is loaded before the DOM is ready.

To avoid this kind frustration, is a good habit to place your javascript before the  tag.